# Overload an Operator C++ in given class being the operators from a Different Class

Tags: c++

I have a function multiply and a function sum, with special characteristics, implemented on a given class i.e. (EngineManager). These functions add and multiply integers in a special fashion and they give away as a result a different class i.e. (StandardShare). When I try to implement the overload directly, the compiler promts:
    Overloaded 'operator+' must be a unary or binary operator (has 3 parameters)
    I understand that the third parameter it is referring to is the this pointer. But as I cannot implement them as free methods, given that they use functions from the hos class i.e. (EngineManager), what alternative do i have.

The code should look like this:

```
class EngineManager {

    public function  Shares::StandardShare* addShares(int a, int b){
           //Does Something......
   };

    inline  Shares::StandardShare* operator +(int a, int b){

        return this->addShares(a,b);
    };

};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you expect, to change the meaning of `(2+3)` when there's an `EngineManager` object "nearby"?

Comment: Ok, this counts as operator overloading abuse. Luckily, it's impossible :) Why don't you use normal functions?

Comment: Why does add call multiply? argggggggggggggggggg

Comment: This question is no good (I can't even formulate an answer)

Comment: Give an example of how you want to use this plz !

Comment: the code in the text is the example of what I want

Comment: What I expect is that when I use the operator + in the class EngineManager to have the overloaded behavior

Comment: Type some code where you **USE** the operator and you will understand the problem !

Comment: BTW why use `inline` within a `class` scope?

Comment: (Voice of Tuco) If you have to add shares, add shares, not integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is neither possible, nor a good idea.

It's not possible not only because overloading the + operator that takes two arguments must be a free function, but also because the type of both arguments cannot be a simple built-in type (like `int`). At least of them must be a class or enumerator type.

It's not a good idea because, even if it were possible, the effect of this would not be confined to the class. The overloaded operator would be called everywhere where you include the header file of your class. So suddenly all integer additions across your program would break. But most importantly, it's not a good idea because it breaks the intuitive meaning of using the + operators with two integers. If you change that meaning, you're only creating confusion for no good reason.

Comment: So what do you think should be the best way to implement it, using just the plain functions?

Comment: @user3245438 You already have a working implementation. Just call `EngineManager::addShares()`.